# Installer - How to get exe to run stand alone

Tags: c#, installation

I have created a winforms project, and created an installer for it.

When installed i can run the exe from the install location, however if i create an entry in my install package to add the project output (the exe) to the users programmes menu or desktop then it fails

Does anyone know why this might be?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a VS Deployment project, you don't add the project output directly, you create a shortcut from within the File System Viewer pointing to the primary output (which you will probably find in the 'Application Folder' in the shortcut dialog). You can then assign the shortcut a name and icon etc.

Comment: i can only make a shortcut to the primary output from within the application folder - (using the file system browser) - i cant do it from either Users Desktop or Users Programe Menu

Comment: What happens when you select Users Desktop and then Create New Shortcut? Or is the option unavailable?

Answer (score 0):

You need both the `EXE` and the `MSI`.